# Print in the same not in a pop-up new seperated page

Tags: javascript, css, printing, popup, text-editor

I found a great rich text editor [A simple but complete rich text editor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content#Example_A_simple_but_complete_rich_text_editor)

and the only problem i have is the printed page of the text editor that pop-up in a new and seperated page but i want it to be in the same page so how can i modify it to reach that ?

```js
function printDoc() {
  if (!validateMode()) { return; }
  var oPrntWin = window.open("","_blank","width=450,height=470,left=400,top=100,menubar=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes");
  oPrntWin.document.open();
  oPrntWin.document.write("<!doctype html><html><head><title>Print<\/title><\/head><body onload=\"print();\">" + oDoc.innerHTML + "<\/body><\/html>");
  oPrntWin.document.close();
}
```

Comment: It shows you all the data in text editor as printable section, how do you want to show in same html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a iframe in your HTML like below

```
 <iframe id="inlineFrameExample" name="inlineFrameExample" title="Inline Frame Example" width="0" height="0">
  </iframe>
```

and in yur printDoc function, instead of `_blank` , pass this iframe name `inlineFrameExample`

```
var oPrntWin = window.open("", "inlineFrameExample", "width=450,height=470,left=400,top=100,menubar=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,scrollbars=yes");
```

**Explanation**

var window = window.open(url, [windowname](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open), [windowFeatures]);

**windowName**

A **DOMString** specifying the name of the browsing context (window, <**iframe**> or tab) into which to load the specified resource; if the name doesn't indicate an existing context, a new window is created and is given the name specified by windowName.

Comment: It is a great solution that work like you describe but when I write RTL text the printed page show text LTR you can check this test website [link](https://unripened-amperes.000webhostapp.com/) to see how things works and if you want i can provide you with whole script of the editor